# How to find beta from the information given?

Tags: finance, beta, mean-variance

This is an exam question. I know that to find beta I need the covariance between the portfolio and asset A but don't know how to find it.

[image: The Question]

Answer (score 1):

Investor I: market portfolio is consisting of 75% of asset A and 25% of asset B, i.p $r_m=3/4r_a+1/4r_b$
$\Rightarrow $ cov($r_a,r_m$)$=$cov($r_a,3/4r_a+1/4r_b$)=$3/4V(r_a)$.

Investor J: market portfolio is consisting of 50% of asset A and 50% of asset B, i.p $r_m=1/2r_a+1/2r_b$
$\Rightarrow $ cov($r_a,r_m$)$=$cov($r_a,1/2r_a+1/2r_b$)=$1/2V(r_a)$.

Comment: Isn't it: $Cov(r_a,3/4r_a+1/4r_b)=3/4V(r_a)+1/4Cov(r_a,r_b)$ ?

Comment: yeah but cov is 0 in the example